# Why is Lie’s first theorem not global?

Tags: differential-geometry, category-theory, manifolds, lie-groups, lie-algebras

On nLab’s page on [Lie’s three theorems](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Lie%27s+three+theorems), Lie’s theorem 2 says that the functor $Lie: \textsf{Local LieGp} \rightarrow \textsf{Finite Dim LieAlg}$ is fully faithfull, and Lie’s theorem 3 says this functor is essentially surjective, so there is an equivalence of categories. But Lie’s theorem 1 is purely local. They say:

> Here one lacks a good notion of differentiable manifold for extending this to a global result.

**What good notion of differentiable manifold is lacking?**

Is our notion of differentiable manifolds too general or too strict? Is the category $\textsf{DiffMan}$ not ‘nice’ enough? I hope someone can explain to me what they mean.

Comment: Note that page distinctly does not say that the functor is an equivalence of categories but that it establishes one between **local** Lie groups and Lie algebras. My category theory is rusty but geometrically speaking there are several non-isomorphic Lie groups with the same Lie algebra. Having the same Lie algebra only guarantees a "local" isomorphism (they look the same near the identity) e.g. the spin group and the special orthogonal group.

Comment: @Callum You are right, I have changed this

Comment: If you restrict to simply connected Lie groups, then you get an isomorphism.